# Wix Installer Project 'iis:CertificateReference' refernced to default and custom https ports

Tags: ssl, iis, https, wix

I have wix setup project. Following are things to happen:

1. Enabling IIS
2. Instaling a self-signed certificate
3. Adding custom `https` port
4. And finally referencing the certificate to the port.

After the setup is successfully installed, the bindings added in `Default Web Site` are default ports for http (80), https (443) and the custom https port. But in IIS manager it can be ssen that both the https port does not have any certificate referenced.

Whereas, while checking fro command prompt with following command `netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443`, the self-signed certificate is refernced to both the https ports.

Following is the certificate install code in wix setup project

```xml
<Component Id="Certificate" Guid="random-guid" 
                   Permanent="yes" Directory="WWWROOT" 
                   KeyPath="yes" >
            <iis:Certificate Id="cert" 
                             BinaryKey="Certificate.Binary"
                             Name="SelfSignedCertificate" 
                             Request="no" 
                             StoreLocation="localMachine" 
                             StoreName="trustedPeople" 
                             Overwrite="yes" 
                             PFXPassword="PASSWORD"/>
            <iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" 
                         Description="Default Web Site" 
                         ConfigureIfExists="no"
                         Directory="WWWROOT" >
                <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassignedHttps"
                                Port="450"
                                IP="*"
                                Secure="yes"  />
                <iis:CertificateRef Id="cert"/>
            </iis:WebSite>
</Component>
```

Question: Why is certificate refernced to both the https ports?

Comment: `the self-signed certificate is refernced to both the https ports` What is the another port? 443? If the 443 port bound to other certificates before install wix? IIS doesn't allow you create a https binding without choose certificate. So port 443 is either bound and a certificate is set before wix is installed, or there is a problem with the wix code and two ports are bound at same time.

Comment: port 443 is not bound to any certificate before. My wix code first activates IIS, then installs the certificate amd finally binds the certificate to custom port

Comment: IIS won't allow sites use 443 port but not bind certificate. What about removing https 443 binding and setup wix installer again?

Comment: I tried that as well, removed the port 443, deactivated IIS and then re-installed. But port 443 for Https and 80 for http seems to be added by default

Comment: I tried again today. Deleted the port 443 from bindings list, deactivated IIS. And then after building my project, installed the app and this time after IIS was activated, the custom https port was added and the defaullt port for http (80) was added to the list of bindings.